# Is it possible to give token access to link to amazon s3 storage?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Problem is this. I am building Laravel app, simple archive for documents with some meta data on Amazon S3.

There are restrictions per for reading file, not all users can access to every file on S3.

Is it possible to grant permissions to user, without Amazon account, to link on file on S3. Something like token in url or something like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105360/laravel-s3-how-to-incorporate-permissions-and-policies-for-authorization

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Answer (score 2):

After some fiddling, this is basically working for me, using Laravel:

first you need to install the AWS PHP SDK (ie via composer: `composer require aws/aws-sdk-php`)

Then observe the following:

[image: how to create a signed url using AWS PHP SDK]

and here's that in copy-pastable code:

```php
// create the S3 client
$s3Client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region' => config('services.ses.region'),
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [ // pass in our credentials here
        'key' => config('services.ses.key'),
        'secret' => config('services.ses.secret'),
    ]
]);

$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'videos', // bucket name
    'Key' => 'videos/'.$download->video_id . '/' . $download->video->filename // path to the object in the bucket
]);

// create a pre-signed request
$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();
```

EDIT: if you would like to then send that file to the browser for download, this should get you going:

```php
return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($presignedUrl, $download) {
    echo file_get_contents($presignedUrl);
}, $download->video->filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app can generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which grants time-limited access to a private object.

It only takes a few lines of code to generate and does not require an API call to AWS to generate the link.

The pre-signed URL can then be used to link to a page, or even within a page (eg in `<img>` tags).

Typically, a pre-signed URL is generated when a user requests access to some private data and is limited to a minimal amount of time (eg 5 minutes). This is better than generating long-lived links and storing them somewhere.

Comment: care to explain _how_?

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes See the linked documentation. If you have a _specific_ question about using pre-signed URLs, feel free to create a new question.

Comment: think I got it figured